# How can I show non editable field in django form

Tags: django, django-forms, field

I've got a model with field `datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`. In form created from this model I don't need to edit this field but I need to show it. The fields with `auto_now_add=True` automatically isn't shown. What is the best way to show this field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you pass an `instance` when creating form object, you can access it in your template using:

```
{{ form.instance.datetime|date:"Y/m/d H:i:s" }}
```

If you don't have an instance, though, the smartest thing to do would be to use current time:

```
{% now "Y/m/d H:i:s" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can display the instance value when editing form like this:

```
{{ form.instance.datetime }}
```

Comment: While simple, the value shown will differ from the value ultimately put into the database.

Comment: @S.Lott Why is that? I assume you're talking about timezone difference, but I was thinking, in terms of l10n it should automatically display correct format for each country, unlike strict formatting (assuming you have the right settings and django ver)..